# certificateValidationMode None not working

Tags: adfs, certificate

I have a problem with our dev environment. We make use of a self certificate what results in the error:

Microsoft.SharePoint.SPImmutableCertificateValidator.Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate) +1274

so what i would like to do is to turn off the validation in our environment. I did find the following fix:

`<authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />`

it doesn't seem to work.

here is a sample of a part of the web.config

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
<service saveBootstrapTokens="true">
  <audienceUris />
  <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPPassiveIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <issuerTokenResolver type="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPIssuerTokenResolver, Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <securityTokenHandlers>
    <clear />
    <add type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add type="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSaml11SecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
      <samlSecurityTokenRequirement>
        <nameClaimType value="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2009/08/claims/userid" />
      </samlSecurityTokenRequirement>
    </add>
    <add type="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPTokenCache, Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  </securityTokenHandlers>
  <federatedAuthentication>
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="false" issuer="https://none" realm="https://none" />
    <cookieHandler mode="Custom" path="/">
      <customCookieHandler type="Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPChunkedCookieHandler, Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    </cookieHandler>
  </federatedAuthentication>
  <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
</service>
```

Comment: Can you add some context to the error ?  Any ULS entries and surrounding items would help as well.  As far as the web.config - SharePoint has more than one.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint supports self signed certificates.  You may need to add it to the trusted root certificates.

1. Export the cert without the private key
2. Open Central Administration =>Security =>Manage Trust
3. Add a new entry and where it asks for new trusted root authority upload your certificate